# regex extract meeting id from zoom link

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of zoom links:

```js
[
    "https://studygroup.zoom.us/j/94760481101?pwd=SVhsUnVoTFpUYjJhOE4rSnNVM3MvUT09",
    "https://studygroup.zoom.us/j/97335370546",
]
```

I want to extract id, which expected results are:

```js
[
    "94760481101",
    "97335370546",
]
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: `link.matchAll(/(\/j\/)(\d+)/g).next().value[2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let links = [
    "https://studygroup.zoom.us/j/94760481101?pwd=SVhsUnVoTFpUYjJhOE4rSnNVM3MvUT09",
    "https://studygroup.zoom.us/j/97335370546"
]

let lnk=links.map(l=>l.split('/').pop().split('?').shift());

console.log(lnk);
```